# iPhone: Line connectors attached to shapes

Tags: iphone, core-graphics, shapes, bezier, connector

How would you draw a line connector between two shapes, such that the line draws with the proper angles and move along with any movement of the shapes?

Something like this:

[image]

I imagine a UIBezier Curve is what I need, but any tutorials or help in getting started would be appreciated.

Comment: Did u get a logic to connect them - when to draw a straight line and when to draw a 90 degree one?

Comment: No. haven't gotten very far yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [UIBezierPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html) is the right way to go, so you should definitely read up on it. I wrote a quick example for making a path there are many more options I'm not using.

Drawing the paths is not the difficult part. **You'll have to track all the boxes you create and store the connections between them** somehow, it depends greatly on how you store the boxes but a relational database feels like the right solution. Given these objects and connections, you'll generate paths in drawrect for one of your views.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    // say we already created a "Make" box
    UIBoxThing *make = ...
    // and here we already created a "Diagrams" box
    UIBoxThing *diagrams = ...

    [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];

    // since we know Diagrams and Make are connected (via some other data), we must draw an arrow between them
    UIBezierPath *path = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
    path.lineWidth = 2;

    // the midpoint of the right side of our first box
    CGPoint start = CGPointMake(make.frame.origin.x+make.frame.size.width, make.frame.origin.y+(make.frame.size.height/2));

    [path moveToPoint:start];

    // the midpoint of the left size of our second box
    CGPoint end = CGPointMake(diagram.frame.origin.x, diagram.frame.origin.y+(diagram.frame.size.height/2));

    [path addLineToPoint:end];

    [path stroke];
}
```

This would be complimented with code that can tell if boxes are to the right of one another or the left, and you can bend the line with addCurveToPoint: or a number of other methods on UIBezierPath. Most of the path stuff is depending on your style, there's no one correct style to connect two points.

Comment: I'll accept this answer. Looking for a good code example. Thanks!